# jquery print on newline

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery code i would like it printing on a new line everytime i click the button.

```
<script language="javascript">
    $('.example-default-value').each(function () {
        var default_value = this.value;
        $(this).focus(function () {
            if (this.value == default_value) {
                this.value = '';
            }
        });
        $(this).blur(function () {
            if (this.value == '') {
                this.value = default_value;
            }
        });
    });
    function example_append() {
        $('#step').append($('#example-textarea'+ /n).val()); 
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are referring to this method and the rest of the code is irrelevant?

```
function example_append() {
    $('#step').append($('#example-textarea').val() + "<br />"); 
}
```

It is HTML, so you need to put a `<br />` for a newline.

Comment: Why is always some one faster then me :)

Answer (score 0):

Add < br > to your append.

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/gGQyp/)